# Thin start with error (`start_unix_server': no unix-domain acceptor (RuntimeError))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, thin

I deployed a rails app to nginx, thin using capistrano (rails 4, ruby 2.1.2, thin 1.6.2, capistrano 2.1.5). I started thin by thin start command. And view some error on this file thin.log. Can anyone show me how to fix that?

Thank you very much!

thin.yml

```
 pid: /home/deploy/myapp/pids/thin.pid
 port: 3000
 timeout: 30
 wait: 30
 log: log/thin.log
 max_conns: 1024
 require: []
 environment: production
 max_persistent_conns: 512
 threaded: true
 no-epoll: true
 daemonize: true
 socket: /home/deploy/myapp/sockets/thin.sock
 chdir: /home/deploy/myapp/current
 address: 0.0.0.0
```

/etc/nginx/sites-availabel/default

```
upstream myapp{
        server 127.0.0.1:3000;
        server 127.0.0.1:3001;
        server 127.0.0.1:3002;
}
server {
        listen   80;
        server_name _;
        character utf-8;


        access_log /home/deploy/myapp/log/access.log;
        error_log /home/deploy/myapp/log/error.log;
        root     /home/deploy/myapp/current/public;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        }

}
```

thin.log

```
Writing PID to /home/deploy/myapp/pids/thin.pid
Using rack adapter
Thin web server (v1.6.2 codename Doc Brown)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on /home/deploy/myapp/sockets/thin.sock, CTRL+C to stop
Exiting!
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:528:in `start_unix_server': no unix-domain acceptor (RuntimeError)
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:528:in `start_server'
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:548:in `start_unix_domain_server'
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/backends/unix_server.rb:19:in `connect'
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `block in start'
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `call'
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:87:in `start'
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/runner.rb:199:in `run_command'
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/runner.rb:155:in `run!'
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/thin-1.6.2/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/thin:23:in `load'
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: When I've been using thin in production, I've been starting it in port 8080 with, thin -e production -p 8080 and have nginx listening for my app on 8080. I don't know if I'm doing it incorrectly but it works.

Comment: @Russell Kompinski: I think i need stop for thin listening in port 3000 because security reason. This code above, i try to use default nginx server to listen in port 80.

Comment: I got the same error, and for me changing the socket name worked. I don't know why yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what my nginx looks like using thin. Maybe it can help.

```
   upstream thin_server {
          server 0.0.0.0:8080 fail_timeout=0;
        }

        server {
                listen   80 default;
                root /home/example/public;
                server_name example.com www.example.com;
                index index.htm index.html;


                location / {
                        try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;
                }

                location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js|mp3|flv|mpeg|avi)$ {
                                try_files $uri @app;
                        }

                 location @app {
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                        proxy_redirect off;
                        proxy_pass http://thin_server;
            }

            error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
            client_max_body_size 4G;
            keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Comment: I tried using socket but it was not working. Can you show me why? I don't understand what different between socket: /home/deploy/myapp/sockets/thin.sock and server 0.0.0.0:8080. :(. Thanks.

Comment: @PhuongTT I'm not sure how to answer that and I don't have a deep understanding about different socket types. Are you asking about the socket address? We're using the socket address which is the ip and port combined of the localhost and port 8080, which is 0.0.0.0:8080. Can you clarify? Also, did that work for you?

Comment: This way is worked for me. I just ask you question to learn more about it. :D

Answer (score 5):

### Generally speaking : configuring Thin and Nginx to work together

I just had almost the same issue on a VPS of mine. What I don't understand is that your Thin config combines port and socket. I don't know if that's a good way to go.

But anyway, here's what I suggest :

#### On the Thin side

You just tell Thin to use the `/home/deploy/myapp/sockets/thin.sock` socket. Alright, we're good. I'd have used another directory for the socket (say `/tmp` or your application's `tmp` directory) but I'm no expert, and that's your call.

#### On the Nginx side

Then if you want Thin and Nginx to communicate, you have to tell Nginx that Thin is listening to incoming request on this particular socket. Here, in your `upstream` block, you tell Nginx that Thin is listening to incoming requests on localhost:3000. Again, as you're using both the port and socket in your Thin conf, I'm not sure if that may be an issue (but at least, one of these settings seems useless to me, as far as the Thin-Nginx communication is concerned). If both Nginx and Thin are used on one same machine, I think sockets are a better way to do this, as they make the communication rely on the filesystem instead of HTTP requests, which should be more efficient. To tell Nginx that Thin is listening on a socket, you have to use an `upstream` block like this one :

```
upstream myapp {
    server unix:/home/deploy/myapp/sockets/thin.sock;
}
```

Judging from your Thin config file, you only have one instance of Thin running for this project, so you only need one `server` line. If you had used say 2 Thin instances (with `servers: 2` in your Thin yml config), you'd have done something like this on the nginx side :

```
upstream myapp {
    server unix:/home/deploy/myapp/sockets/thin.0.sock;
    server unix:/home/deploy/myapp/sockets/thin.1.sock;
}
```

### "No unix-domain acceptor (RuntimeError)"

As for the *"no unix-domain acceptor (RuntimeError)"* error, it might come from a permission issue on the socket directory, at least that was the case when I came accross this problem just now (don't know why, my `sockets` directory was gone, and when I created it again, it had to have the right permissions to avoid this error). So I'd say check this out ;)

Comment: I try to use Unix socket because i think opening port (like port 3000) is security hole.

Answer (score 3):

For me, this error was caused by a missing sockets directory (in your case this would be `/home/deploy/myapp/sockets`).